# 9-Slice-Scaling in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices, symbols, scale

Is it possible to create a 9-Slice-Object within Photoshop? I haven't found that feature yet, and can't find any help through google. Doesn't Photoshop support it?

Comment: you mean separate your file into 3x3 squares?

Comment: @Naty yeah, exactly. And when I scale it the Corners stay sharp and dont get stretched

Answer (score 1):

No. Photoshop does not offer 9-point scaling.

There's a discussion related to this at Adobe's Feedback site:
http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/add_9_slice_scaling_in_photoshop_cs6

Comment: Yeah, we do not yet offer it. There are ways to accomplish this with linked smart objects and masks, but no out of the box support yet. I would love to talk to you folks on how you would use it, to understand how we can offer this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

2 options:
1. Download [Guideguide](http://guideguide.me/) and use it to create a 3*3 guides grid then use it however you want
2. Open illustrator, create a rectangle, go to:

> object>path>split into grid

And then split your rectangle into 3*3, then you can move the vector to illustrator as a smart object, pixels or shape and use it as you want.

Comment: does Guidguide prevent my corners from being stretched? For me it looks like its only generating Guidelines

Comment: can you add a picture? I don't understand what you mean by "corners are stretched"